# Efficient looping algorithm in python

Tags: python, algorithm

I am doing the below operation where the set of values in a dictionary (dictionary_with_large_values) can have more than 1 million values. Looping over each of them is taking lot of time. There are 7 to 8 keys with such data in the dictionary. What is the better algorithm that can be used in python which is more time efficient? The algorithm checks if two strings are same after error checks and create mapping from parent string with list of similar strings(dictionary_test_1). And another dictionary to create a reverse mapping(dictionary_test_2)

```
#type of dictionary. Values contains set of strings
dictionary_with_large_values = defaultdict(set)
dictionary_test_1 = defaultdict(set)
dictionary_test_2 = defaultdict()
# method which stores data to dictionary
# algorithm to parse the data
for k,v in dictionary_with_large_values.items():
    i=0
    values = list(v)
    while i < len(values):
        string_data = values[i].replace(" ", "")
        j = i + 1
        while j < len(values):
            string2_data = values[j].replace(" ", "")
            # algorithm to check if normalized(string_data) == normalized(string2_data)
            data = areTheySame(string_data,string2_data)
            if data:
                dictionary_test_1[values[i]].add(values[j])
                dictionary_test_2[values[j]] = values[i]
                del values[j]
            else:
                j += 1
        i += 1
```

Comment: why are you sorting ```v``` if you are going to compare each pair of element anyway?

Comment: The sort is optional. Even I remove that, its very slow in computation.

Comment: Can you explain the intent of the code? The code is a guide, but knowing what your intent is helps figure it out faster. Looks like you're just splitting strings that are "normalized" matches into two different output `dict`s, but the code is odd as is (e.g. why is `dictionary_test_2` a `defaultdict` with no `default_factory`, making it effectively an ugly `dict`?).

Comment: @ShadowRanger, Sorry if it caused confusion. I clarified in the problem statement.

Comment: @KishoreKumar: I suspect it would help a lot if you could make this a true [MCVE]. Without knowing what constitutes a quasi-duplicate, it's unclear if there is an algorithmically superior solution to the `O(n²)` all-to-all testing (that, assuming each `v` is pretty large, is almost certainly the biggest expense in your program). If you could convert values to a normalized form where strict equality works, or to a sortable form where quasi-duplicates would be adjacent, that cost might drop to `O(n)` or `O(n log n)`.